# Get data-attribute in onepage-scroll pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute, onepage-scroll

I use [One Page Scroll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) for full screen carousel. I want to display `data-attribute` in pagination. So far, I am able to display number of slides in pagination. How can I get `data-attribute` in pagination?

Here I want to display years in pagination.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main" class="main">
  <section data-year="1950" class="page1">
  <div class="page_container">
    <h1>Forward Thinking</h1>
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"</p>
    </div>
</section>
<section data-year="1960" class="page2">
  <div class="page_container">
    <h1>iPhone 5S</h1>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."</p>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('ul.onepage-pagination li a').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var li = elem.parent();
    var ul = li.parent();
    elem.html((li.index() + 1) + '/' + ul.children().length);
});
```

Comment: The markup seems to be missing. Please share the markup for `ul.onepage-pagination li a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data attribute of the right `section`, you can use the `index` provided by the `.each()` function you already use.

With that index, you can target the right `section` and retreive its `data-year` using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

In the snippet below (*please run it in full page*), I've hidden the icon showing which section is active... And quickly played with CSS to maximize the usage of the text links.

```js
$(".main").onepage_scroll();

var sections = $(".main section");

$('ul.onepage-pagination li a').each(function(index) {
  var elem = $(this);
  var li = elem.parent();
  var ul = li.parent();
  
  elem.html(sections.eq(index).data("year")+" - "+(li.index() + 1) + '/' + ul.children().length);
});
```

```css
.onepage-pagination ul{
  with:6em;
}
.onepage-pagination a{
  width:100% !important;
}
.onepage-pagination a:before{
  display:none !important;
}
.onepage-pagination a.active{
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/onepage-scroll/1.3.1/onepage-scroll.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/onepage-scroll/1.3.1/jquery.onepage-scroll.min.js"></script>

<div id="main" class="main">
  <section data-year="1950" class="page1">
    <div class="page_container">
      <h1>Forward Thinking</h1>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section data-year="1960" class="page2">
    <div class="page_container">
      <h1>iPhone 5S</h1>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/geVapG)

Comment: Other contents are not displayed with this slider - like footer below the slider. How can I display this?

Comment: It takes the whole space by desing... You can place your footer in the last `section`.

Comment: When I integrated it on **Wordpress** with header - everything is broken. Without header it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using jQuery in your example. You can get attributes from HTML Elements via `.attr()` as described in their [official docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

In your example you just have to call `.attr('data-year')` on the corresponding element to get its value.

Comment: I applied ``.attr('data-year')`` in above function. But it displays the same **(1950)** data throughout the whole pagination.

Comment: your query-selector in your example is `ul.onepage-pagination li a` but in your html you added the `data-year` attribute to `section`. May you have to iterate over `.main section` instead of `ul.onepage-pagination li a`?